# States in react not getting updated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ajax

Inside the verifyPassword function when I am trying to update the state of user using setUser, it is not updating. Therefore the values of input remain the same and also when I console log user it is empty.
I have also tried by first storing the res object from .done method in another variable and then update the state, but that didn't work too.
below is the code.

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import $ from "jquery";


function ChangeDetails(props){
    var [pass , setPass] = useState("");
    var [user , setUser] = useState({
        name:"",
        phone:"",
        email:""
    });
    var [auth ,setAuth] = useState(false);
    function passChange(e){
        let password = e.target.value;
        setPass(password);
    }
    function verifyPassword(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("http://localhost:4000/details" , {username: sessionStorage.getItem("User") , password: pass})
        .done((res)=>{
            let {name , phone, email} = res;
            console.log(name);
            setUser=({
                name:name,
                phone:phone,
                email:email
            })
            console.log(user);
            console.log(res);
            setAuth(true);
        })
        .fail(e=>{console.log(e);})
        
    }
    function handleChange(e){
        let {name , value} = e.target;
        setUser(prevValue=>{
            return {
                ...prevValue,
                [name] : value
            }
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Change Your Details here @{sessionStorage.getItem("User")}</h1>
            {!auth && <form onSubmit={verifyPassword}>
                <h2>Verify by entering Password</h2>
                <input onChange={passChange} value={pass} type="password" name="password" />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>}
            {auth && <form>
                <label>Name:
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={user.name}  name="name"   id="name" /></label><br />
                <label>Phone Number:
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={user.phone} name="phone"  id="phone" /></label><br />
                <label>Email:
                <input type="email" onChange={handleChange} value={user.email} name="email"   id="email" /></label><br />
                <button>Change</button>
            </form>}
        </div>
    );
}
export default ChangeDetails;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: State updates are async. `console.log`ing the `user` directly after calling `setUser` will not reflect the updated state. The new state will only be visible during the next render that gets triggered by the state update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got typo on setUser within verifyPassword function

you typed setUser=

it should be setUser()

Comment: Damn, I didn't realize this...Really thanks sir for watching the code this closely.

Comment: sure, no probs. fyi, you may accepted this as an answer to close the question off.

Answer (score 2):

Because `setUser` is a funtion to update state. Use

```
setUser({
  name:name,
  phone:phone,
  email:email
})
```

instead of

```
setUser = ({
  name:name,
  phone:phone,
  email:email
})
```